# Cordova-how to create links for only work in phonegap app?

Tags: php, cordova

how to create links for only work in phonegap app,when user extract app and see links and open in any browser to disable that links in any browser .how to create links working only through phonegap app.
For example: `<a href="http://www.example.com/product.php?id=1">products</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom url scheme for your application. for example your custom url scheme can be myapp:// and when user click a link like myapp://test.html, page open in your app. Please see the two Corodva plugins:

1. [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)
2. [LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin](http://LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin)